# Configuring AngularJS Routes on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a difficult time configuring AngularJS Routes on Rails. I know that this is a basic concept and have read: http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/, but it seems I am still a bit confused.

I currently have a Rails routes.rb file that I would like to set up to process angularRoutes first and if its not an angular route, then fall back to rails. The link above says to include the follow 2 lines of code:

```
 root 'application#index'
 get '*path' => 'application#index'
```

which will thus direct the root page to the application controller's index method. In that case, I am not quite sure how Angular gets a chance to do its routing.

I am unsure what to put inside my routes.rb file for my Rails Project so that Angular routes would execute first.

My angular routes:

```
# Define the carmel application
@carmel = angular.module('carmel',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute',
    'templates',
])

# Define our routes
 @carmel.config([
   '$routeProvider',
   '$locationProvider',
   ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->

    console.log("HEre1");

    $routeProvider.when '/',
        templateUrl: '<%= asset_path("production/index.html") %>'
        controller:  'ProductionIndexCtrl'
        resolve: {

        }

    # So we don't have "#" in the url's.  Magic.
    $locationProvider.html5Mode true
])
```

(I would like the root path to direct to my angular templateURL and controller, currently I am getting an error.)

ActionView::MissingTemplate at /

Missing template application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/Users/simon_zhu/Documents/carmel/app/views" * "/Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/jasmine-rails-0.9.0/app/views" * "/Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"

Comment: where do you define you views?

Comment: the view im trying to render is under app/assets/templates/production/index.html.erb and the controller is under app/assets/javascripts/controllers/ProductionIndexCtrl.js.coffee

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a view to render in the `Application#index` action.

Your `routes.rb` file is hitting the `ApplicationController`'s `#index` action, which defaults to `render :index` if you don't set your own `render` or `redirect` action. Your error is from Rails being unable to find this view.

The easiest way to get that is to create an `application` folder under `views` and make a bare-bones `index.html.erb`. This will default to using the `application.html.erb` layout file in `app/views/layout`, which should link your `application.js` manifest, which should list your Angular files.

```
\_ app
  \_ views
    \_ application
     |  - index.html.erb
    \_ layouts
     |  - application.html.erb
```

As long as your combined `app/views/application/index.html.erb` and `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` have `ng-app` and `ng-view` defined, you should be able to see your Angular code running.